# Maticons will not be shown

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, stackblitz

My workmate created a stackblitz-example and i forked his stackblitz (deleted by now) to get the mat-icons working: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/seeming-same-content-but-different-behavior-working

=> this link works. The only thing i changed is: Adding lines 2-7 in styles.scss

He could not reproduce this. So i wanted to show him what i did and so i tried to do it again. And now i can also not get the mat-icons working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/seeming-same-content-but-different-behavior-not-working

=> this link does not work

But i can not find any difference between them.

So, what is wrong in the second? Why are warnings in styles.scss in the not working example but not in the working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-printable characters. In the [non-working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bx8wkj?file=src%2Fstyles.scss), you have some [non-breaking-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) which messes up the syntax.

- You can check that there's a difference (although not visible to the eye) with a tool like [diff](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html).
- Or see the actual non-printable characters (their codes) by copy-pasting you files on [this website](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in styles.scss
for some reason @import is: Unknown at rule @import url.

copy this lines from style.scss -mdqd6o to bx8wkj.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanstc.css");
```